# Full word search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Can you share me an idea on how to do a full word wildcard search in SQL Server?

Assuming I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    ID number,
    Text varchar(3000)
)
```

This is my data:

| ID | Text | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | THIS IS MY **CAR** | (*Note: "CAR" is the last 3 character of the string) |
| 2 | MY DADDY LOOK AFTER ME CAREFULLY | (Note: This sentence does not have the word "CAR") |
| 3 | THIS IS MY **CAR**:). I LOOK AFTER IT CAREFULLY EVERYDAY. | (Note: there is a full stop after the word "CAR") |
| 4 | **CAR**- IS MY LIFE. I LOVE IT MORE THAN EVERYTHING | (Note: There is special character after the word "CAR") |
| 5 | **CAR**! |  |
| 6 | **CAR** |  |
| 7 | TOO MUCH CARBON DIOXIDE IS BAD FOR HEALTH! | (Note: This sentence does not have the word "CAR") |
| 8 | LUCKLY THAT THIS TWINS DOES NOT HAVE ACARDIA. |  |

Now, I need to write a query that will list all rows have the word "CAR".

(i.e. following is the result I am trying to after)

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | THIS IS MY **CAR** |
| 3 | THIS IS MY **CAR**:). I LOOK AFTER IT CAREFULLY EVERYDAY. |
| 4 | **CAR**- IS MY LIFE. I LOVE IT MORE THAN EVERYTHING |
| 5 | **CAR**! |
| 6 | **CAR** |

Where ID 2,7 and 8 are omitted as they don't have the word "CAR" even they have some words that contains the three characters "C-A-R".

Anyone can share me some light on using SQL in SQL Server will be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend you do some research on this subject rather than expecting us to do it all for you. Its a big subject and there is a lot of information already available on it.

Comment: Hi Dale, I actually tried to search it on the internet and have no idea. Forgive me for a bit third world country. Could you please share me some link would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Just putting your title into google gives hundreds of results.

Comment: Let me try again. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this (won't be fast) is the following:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(20) = 'CAR';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE CONCAT('#',TextColumn,'#') LIKE CONCAT('%[^a-z]',@string,'[^a-z]%')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry . I was confused by the question, I adjusted the answer, see below

```
select * from Table_10 
where ('.' + Table_10.Text + '.') LIKE '%[^a-z]CAR[^a-z]%'
```

Comment: I found this query completely independent and not based on the above answer. So I posted it just to correct the previous query.

Comment: I understand, but given the other answer has been there for an hour, it doesn't really add value to repeat it.

Comment: It meant to me that I could do it. haha thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains to search any words or phrase:

```
select * from table1  where Contains(text,'CAR');
```